# While opening Gmail, following error occurs- Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string, 
The code I am using is following:                 
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Software\\geckodriver-
v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver wd= new FirefoxDriver();
wd.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
//wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();
wd.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
WebElement e1= wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
e1.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']/content/span[text()='Ne
xt']")).click();
```

---

error log

---

error log
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.usingFirefoxBinary(GeckoDriverService.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at register_prctc.gmail.main(gmail.java:15)

Comment: that's an ongoing issue with the gecodriver, downgrade to v0.15 wiith selenium 3.3.1

Comment: @AbhijitDatta Can you try bumping up your Selenium to 3.4.0, geckodriver to v0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox to 53.x and try out the execution. let me know the status. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question:

1. To work with Selenium 3.4.0, geckodriver v0.16.1 & latest Mozilla Firefox 53.x you need to set the absolute path of the geckodriver in your code as:
   `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\your_dir\\geckodriver.exe");`
2. As per best practices you should not use `Thread.sleep(6000)`, instead use `ImplicitlyWait` or `ExplicitWait`.
3. The xpath `.//[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a` you used doesn't identifies any unique element. To find the element `Gmail` link you can use the `linkText` locator as:

   ```
   wd.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
   ```
4. For sending text into `Email or Phone` field provide a unique `xpath` as:

   ```
   WebElement e1= wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
   ```
5. The xpath to click on `Next` button looks vulnerable to me, you may like to change it to : `wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']/content/span[text()='Next']")).click();`
6. Here is the working set of your own code with some simple tweaks:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
   WebDriver wd= new FirefoxDriver();
   wd.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
   wd.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
   WebElement e1= wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
   e1.sendKeys("id@gmail.com");
   wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']/content/span[text()='Next']")).click();
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: facing another problem.-xception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V---    *****and every solutions of this issue are provided in Guava, but i don't use it..can u fix this matter??

Comment: @AbhijitDatta Well, you don't need guava, can you please update your current code block & the current error stacktrace in the question area for me to interpret what's​ happening. Thanks

Comment: updated code and error log in question section.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AbhijitDatta Please do the following: 1. Copy geckodriver to a convenient location, preferably within "C:\\some_folder". 2. Change the path in your code. 3. Clear your Mozilla Firefox browser cache & history entirely. 4. If possible run CCleaner to clear all the rotten stuffs from your PC. 5. Restart your PC. 6. Remove unwanted code. 7. Execute your code. 8. Let me know the status. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove Selenium-java-2.53.1.jar file and update all jars

[image]